# Neo4j Shell does not work

Tags: shell, neo4j

As I double Click on Neo4jShell in windows the shell opens with this error

Warning! This batch script has been deprecated. Please use the provided PowerShell scripts instead: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/powershell.html

I have updated my windows with Windows6.1-KB2506143-x64 and have installed the latest version of Java but this problem exists. Would you please help me?

Comment: have you tried to start it with powershell as it's said in the error? the link it provides gives you everything to do it. EDIT: This is just a warning by the way, it should run fine if it's the only one you have.

Comment: I have downloaded noe4j.zip from the neo4j site and in the bin folder in this path : \neo4j-community-3.0.0-M03-windows\neo4j-community-3.0.0-M03\bin\Neo4jShell.bat I double click on Neo4jShell.bat and in the page that was opened I received this warning and I can not type anything in the opened page.

Comment: I think I have not installed the powershell correctly, would you please let me know how should I install it? I have downloaded Neo4j 3.0.0-M04 (Windows x64, exe) file  from http://neo4j.com/download/other-releases/  is this the right file for installing the powershell?

Comment: I think you should go with the desktop installer instead.

Comment: The docs for powershell are here: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/powershell.html

Comment: The exe is the desktop installer which doesn't neeed bat files and also doesn't need the powershell files.

Comment: Thanks a lot I had some misunderstandings about the powershell

Answer (score 0):

In short use the desktop-installer to install and start/stop Neo4j.

The [powershell scripts](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/powershell.html) are for advanced users / admins.